# Google Play Console / Proguard : lines of crash reports do not correspond to my code

Tags: java, android, android-studio, proguard, android-proguard

I use Proguard in my app. My problem is that the lines of my crash reports in Google Play Console do not correspond to the lines in my code.

Here are the settings of my code:

In my Gradle (app) file:

```
   buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }   
    }
```

In the app directory of my project, I have got the file proguard-rules.pro Here is its content:

```
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
```

I imported the file mapping.txt (located in /app/build/outputs/mapping/release) to the Google Play Console.

So why do I have this problem with my lines numbers in my crash reports ?

Thanks.